# Post to more than one friend's wall using Facebook Sdk for Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do we post to more than one Friend's wall using Facebook Sdk for Android ?
In the publish feed dialog, "to" parameter is taking only one ID. How do we pass an array of IDs to it and publish to more than one wall using only one publish feed dialog ?

Thanks

Comment: what you tried for it? share some code.